# Как обработать в одном ресте 2 запроса, url и набор данных у которы одинаковы но в них меняется только @QueryParametr? Java

Tags: java, spring, controller

Я использую spring, у меня есть один сервис и две его имплементации. В зависимости от того какой @QueryParametr я получу мне нужно выбрать 1 из 2 сервисов в котором его обработать. 
Варианты, можно например создать 3ий сервис, и в нем через условие отфильтровать если @QueryParametr = 101 то вызываем сервис 1, если @QueryParametr = 102 - сервис 2. Но это решение мне не подходит, нужно более грамотное. Потому что в дальнейшем добавятся еще другие @QueryParametrы

Comment: В ваш service добавляете к примеру метод/поле, которое возвращает список поддерживаемых значений параметра. В контроллере список сервисов. Перебираете его, если  сервис поддерживает параметр - вызываете обработку

Comment: по-другому, кроме как фильтровать вручную, не получится